# How can I remove the IM status entries from the messaging indicator?

Tags: 11.10, configuration, indicator

On 11.10:

I know how to remove the email & u1 entries using blacklist/remove from `/usr/share/blablabla_youknowwhere`

but I see no entries or solutions on how to remove only the status entries, as I dont use any IMs, only mail & u1.

I suspect its hardcoded, please let me be wrong. but if it is so, maybe someone enlightened got a diff/patch, although I fear it will lead to dependency hell (compiling wise)

Comment: It is hardcoded and I don't know of any patch, but I don't see the reason why such a patch would lead to dependency hell, as it would be *removing* things rather than adding. If you just remove things, you can keep the exact same set of dependencies.